# Struct vectors and functions in other files

Tags: c++, vector, struct

In my program I have a file that contains the main function and another file that contains other functions. I have a struct and have created a vector of it:

```
struct Animal {
    string name;
    string type;
    string regestration;
    int problem;
};
vector<Animal> animals;
```

In my header file for the other functions I have the following:

```
void loadAnimals(string &file, vector<Animal> animals);
```

When compiling I get the error : `'Animal' was not declared in this scope`
for the above line.

Do I need to declare the struct again in the header file? Or am I just using the wrong syntax

Comment: It's not exactly clear to me what you're doing. When asking about issues with setups that involve multiple files, it's quite important to describe what happens in which file exactly (What headers are we talking about? In which file does the error occur? Where are things declared? Where are they defined? What is included where in which order?). But, in general, anything needs to be declared before it can be used. In your case, you'll even need a definition of `Animal` for `vector<Animal>` to work, not just a declaration…

Comment: What you need to do is read stackoverflow.com's [help], with specific instructions about [ask] questions that are answerable, as well as the basic rules for creating a [mcve] for demonstrating your issue. Unless your question contains a minimal example that anyone can cut and paste, verbatim, and attempt to compile it and reproduce your ***exact*** problem, it is unlikely that anyone will be able to figure out what your problem is. What's currently shown in the question is insufficient information.